# problem with inputs for estimating earth mover distance with emd from python ot package

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, distance, earth-movers-distance

when implementing the `emd` and `emd2` functions from the `ot` package [here](https://pythonot.github.io/_modules/ot/lp.html#emd2) I'm a little confused on how to input `a`,`b` to be consistent with `M`, the cost matrix.

without the `a`,`b` inputs, things work as I expect them:

```
import ot
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(943)
d1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=(50,2)) #multivariate distribution 1: Nxk, N=50, k=2
d2 = np.random.normal(2,1,size=(50,2)) #multivariate distribution 2: Nxk, N=50, k=2
C = ot.dist(d1,d2,metric='euclidean') #cost matrix with elements |i-j|
print(C.shape) #NxN
otp = ot.emd([],[],C) #optimal transport plan, also NxN
print('emd: ',np.sum(otp*C)) #emd estimate
emd = ot.emd2([],[],C)
print('emd: ',emd) #or obtain it directly with emd2
#emd values from to preceding print statements
#emd:  2.5941590559952763
#emd:  2.5941590559952763
```

This works as the `a`,`b` inputs are left empty, which according to the documentation means "uniform weights if empty list" are used. My first question is, as this means this assumes a uniform distribution for each of the marginals, isn't this an incorrect emd as the marginals are clearly not uniform? My (potentially incorrect) assumption therefore is that leaving `a`,`b` empty is not the correct distance.

I did see another question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57562613/python-earth-mover-distance-of-2d-arrays) and the solution there also produces the same emd value as the 2 emd values estimated above using only information from the cost matrix as input:

```
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
assignment = linear_sum_assignment(C)
print(C[assignment].sum() / 50) #emd value of 2.594159055995276
```

Now, when I actually try to input `a`,`b` is where my real confusion lies. If I just input the raw observations, the arrays `d1` and `d2` I get the following pretty expected error

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 6 decimals
a and b vector must have the same sum
```

I believe it expects distributions as the docs say these inputs are "Source histogram"; but if I convert the raw data to histograms the shapes are no longer compatible with the cost matrix, as the cost matrix is NxN and the histograms are n_bins x n_bins, leading to another error

```
hist1, _ = np.histogramdd(d1,bins=[2,2],density=True) #shape n_bins x n_bins = 2x2
hist2, _ = np.histogramdd(d2,bins=[2,2],density=True) #shape n_bins x n_bins = 2x2; while C is NxN
ot.emd2(hist1, hist2, C)

AssertionError: Dimension mismatch, check dimensions of M with a and b
```

Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong either with my implementation and how to correctly implement? ...or if the first implementations without `a` and `b` are correct clarify what the role of `a` and `b` are and why the emd is correct without those inputs?

Comment: have I asked the question clearly? Is there anything I can do to clarify and/or improve the question?